# Import xml file

Tags: excel, vba

I am programming in the VBA source code a logic to import an xml file into excel, but I do not know which function to parse in the spreadsheet.

Trying this command but it does not work:

```
  ActiveWorkbook.XmlImport Url:=sArquivo, ImportMap:=Nothing, Overwrite:=True, Destination:=Range("$A$1")
```

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE CFXML [
```

I want to import the tags: 
`"<ProductDescription>", "<Quantity>", "<MonetaryAmount>", "<ProductTypeCode>", "<ProprietaryProductIdentifier>", "<ProductIdentifierTypeCode>"`.

Comment: have you tried recording the action you do manually to import an excel. Enable recording on Developer tab on Data tab, New query, From XML

Comment: Where's your XML? You need to either flatten it with XSLT to import or parse nodes by their levels with XPath to retrieve values.